# Is there any way to systematically do all epsilon delta proofs?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

If you want to prove that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ to $a$ is equal to $L$ using the epsilon-delta definition of the limit, you need to solve the inequality

$$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

for $x$, getting it into the form

$$|x-a|<\delta$$

for some $\delta$, which will in general be a function of $\epsilon$.

My question is, is there some way to calculate the function $\delta(\epsilon)$, short of solving the inequality above using the function $f$ you have?

Is it at least possible if $f$ is sufficiently well behaved?  Like if $f$ is differentiable, can you calculate $\delta(\epsilon)$ using the derivative of $f$?

EDIT: [This journal paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311156) shows a formula for polynomials.  If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_n (x-a)^n$, then to prove that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $a$ equals $f(a)$, we can let $\delta = min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{ \sum_{n=1}^{k} |a_n|})$.

Can this be generalized to Taylor series?  If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-a)^n$, then can we prove that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $a$ equals $f(a)$ by letting $\delta = min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|})$ ?

Comment: No you don't need to solve that inequality, rather you have to find a $\delta$ which ensures that the inequality holds. Solving inequalities via algebraic manipulation misses the whole concept of limit. The right approach to learn these things is to study proofs of limit theorems. And then apply the same technique to the problems given in book.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not actually interested in doing epsilon-delta proofs.  I'm long past that in my mathematical career.  I'm just interested in whether it's possible to come up with a general formula for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: See my 19 August 2001 sci.math post [How to cheat with polynomial epsilon/delta proofs](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=330970) and Gerald A. Edgar's [same-day follow-up comments](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=330971).

Comment: There can't be formula for $\delta$ for the simple reason that if one value of $\delta$ works a smaller one also works. Neither is $\delta$ a function of $\epsilon $. What is needed is show the existence of a $\delta$ and there is no specific requirement of obtaining an expression for it in terms of other parameters.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The fact that smaller deltas work does not imply there can’t be a formula for delta.  There could be a formula for the greatest possible delta that works.  Or there could be a formula that’s guaranteed to generate some delta, even if it’s not the greatest delta that could work.  Neither one of those things is mathematically impossible.

Comment: Ok,but I don't get the point of such a formula even if can be found in case of certain simple functions (like the ones in exercises).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Well, let’s say you were writing an automatic theorem prover to construct epsilon-delta proofs.  What algorithm would you give it?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, your sci.math post and the journal paper you cited were helpful.  Do you think this could be generalized to Taylor series?  I edited my question to ask that.

Comment: The algorithm can be given for a well defined class of functions, but not for arbitrary functions. Thus for example the limit theorems cover the case of rational functions. Using composition law and standard limits we can handle the elementary functions as well.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do you think it would be possible to come up with a formula for arbitrary power series?  See my edit.

Comment: Your formula for power series cannot work in general. There are power series $\sum_n a_n x^n$ which are continuous at $0$, but such that $\sum_n |a_n|$ diverges. (For example, the geometric series $\sum_n x^n$ has this property.) You could get something similar that would work by using the radius of convergence of a series, but if you won't accept an answer that involves the Lipschitz constant of a function you probably won't accept that either...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan you should say $\delta(\epsilon)$ is the smallest delta that works. Otherwise, it's not a well-defined function

Comment: @Micah Does my formula at least work for power series for which the sum of coefficients converges?

Comment: @mathworker21 I would be fine with a formula that gives the smallest delta that works.  I would also be fine with a formula that for any given (sufficiently well-behaved) function is always guaranteed to generate a function $\delta(\epsilon)$ that works for that function, whether it’s the smallest delta that works or not.  For instance I have no idea whether the $\delta(\epsilon)$ for polynomials described in my edit is the smallest possible delta (I’m guessing it’s not), but it’s still valid,

Comment: I haven't worked through the details, but your formula should work except that maybe some strict inequalities will become non-strict (which you could fix by dividing by $2$).

Comment: @Micah OK, if you can confirm that and post an answer based on that, I'd be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: Your idea for  power series will generally not work because  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$   may be $\infty.$ For example if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n $  for $|x|<1$, and $a=0$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah, Micah made that point.  But if the sum of the coefficients converges, then it does work.  See Micah’s answer.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet And now see zhw's answer.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835433/can-continuity-always-be-shown-by-using-ε-δ/2836909#2836909) at math.stackexchange asks essentially the same thing for "elementary" functions. For example, my answer to that gives a computable induction that produces a formula for $\delta(\epsilon)$, including in the case of polynomials, by iteratively applying the elementary limit theorems (and their proofs) from Calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I deal with the power series question. I'll use your notation and assume WLOG that $a=0.$

Here's a simple solution to the general $\delta = \varphi(\epsilon)$ question that uses a different idea. Suppose the radius of convergence of the series is $r\in (0,\infty).$ Then

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1},\,\,|x|<r.$$

Define $D=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|a_n|(r/2)^{n-1}.$ Then for $|x|<r/2,$ the mean value theorem gives

$$|f(x)-f(0)| = |f'(c_x)||x| \le D|x|.$$

Thus $\delta = \min(r/2,\epsilon/D)$ is a solution.

Note that since $r = 1/\limsup |a_n|^{1/n},$ we really do have a formula for $\delta $ as a function of $\epsilon$ that depends only on the coefficients $a_1,a_2, \dots.$ Note also that in the case $r=\infty,$ we can replace $r/2$ by $1$ in the above, and everything goes through.

Now to your specific question: Does $\delta = \min(1,\epsilon/(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|))$ work? The answer is yes, assuming $\sum|a_n| < \infty.$

Proof: Because $\sum|a_n| < \infty,$ the power series defining $f$ has radius of convergence at least $1.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Set $\delta = \min(1,\epsilon/(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|)).$ If $|x|<\delta,$ then

$$|f(x)-f(0)| = |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n||x|^n$$ $$ = |x| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n||x|^{n-1} \le  |x| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n| <\epsilon.$$

This result covers all cases where the radius of convergence is greater than $1.$ But obviously the result fails if $\sum|a_n| = \infty.$ Here we are in the case where the radius of convergence $r$ is a number in $(0,1].$ This can be handled by scaling into the  $\sum|a_n| < \infty$ situation, and then scaling back. But the answer isn't as simple in this case. Since Micah's answer already covers this argument, I'll omit it here. (Note that the first method I mentioned, involving $f'(x),$ does not require this scaling argument.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can it be extended to power series with a smaller radius of convergence, using techniques similar to those used in Micah's answer.

Comment: I changed my answer to give a simple solution based on $f'(x),$ and also to address the specific question you asked.

Comment: OK, I'm accepting your answer and awarding you the bounty.

Comment: Thank you. It was a nice problem to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ can be written as a power series around $0$: that is, $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for some sequence $\{a_n\}$. We'll examine the continuity of $f$ at zero. (Of course, you could shift the power series to some other point and this analysis would apply there as well.)

We'll also start by assuming that $f$ has a radius of convergence which is strictly greater than $1$: this implies that $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent. Later on we'll remove this assumption. Let $P_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of the series. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let  $\delta_n=\min\left(1, \frac{\epsilon/2}{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|}\right)$. Then, by the linked paper, if $|x|<\delta_n$, then $|P_n(x)-a_0|<\epsilon/2$.

Now, take $\delta=\min\left(1, \frac{\epsilon/2}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|}\right)$. Then $\delta \leq \delta_n$ for all $n$. So, if $x<\delta$, then $|P_n(x)-a_0|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n$: that is, $P_n(x)$ lies in the open $(\epsilon/2)$-ball around $a_0$ for all $n$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(x)=f(x)$, it follows that $f(x)$ lies in the closure of that ball. That is, we have $|f(x)-a_0|\leq \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$. So, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can do our $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof with $\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon/2}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|}\right)$.

---

This works when $f$ has a large enough radius of convergence, but what about the general case? In general, to say that $f$ can be written as a power series around $0$ is to say that it has *some* positive radius of convergence. That is, $R=\frac{1}{\limsup (a_k^{1/k})}$ is positive. Fix some $r<R$ (for definiteness, we could take $r=R/2$).

Now, let
$$g(x)=f(x/r)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a_n}{r^n}\right)x^n$$
This is a power series with a radius of convergence $R/r$, which is strictly greater than $1$, and so we can apply our previous result to $g$. That is, given any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta_g=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon/2}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|/r^i}\right)$. Then, if $|x|<\delta_g$, $|g(x)-a_0|<\epsilon$.

Now, let $\delta=r\delta_g$. If $|x|<\delta$, then $x/r<\delta_g$, and so
$|f(x)-a_0|=|g(x/r)-a_0|<\epsilon$. It follows that, for any $f$ which can be written as a convergent power series in a neighborhood of $0$, we can do our $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof with $\delta=r\delta_g=r\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon/2}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|/r^i}\right)$.

---

This answers the question in your edit. In all fairness I should say that I don't think it does a very good job of answering your initial question: being equal to a convergent power series in the neighborhood of a point is a highly restrictive property! (I actually think the deleted answer, which works for any continuously differentiable function, is in many ways superior to this one...)

Comment: The deleted answer didn't give an actual formula for delta that a computer program could use.  It was written in terms of a Lipschitz constant that you don't know the value of, you just know that it exists.  But that's not very useful; after all, you already know that delta itself exists.  Whereas this one is an actual formula for delta.

Comment: In any case, I'm upvoting your answer for the time being, and barring any other answers coming in the next week I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I think my point is that you could come up with a formula for that Lipschitz constant (e.g., as the maximum of $f'$ on some interval of definition) which is about as explicit as my formula for $r$ (which involves a $\limsup$). Basically whenever you have an infinite amount of data that goes into the specification of $f$ you're going to need to control it somehow, which will take some actual analysis...

Comment: OK, if you can come up with a formula for the Lipschitz constant, I'd appreciate it if you add that to your answer.

Comment: By the way, I think you accidentally wrote i=0 rather than i=1 in the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous functions where L=f(a), you need somehow find a relation $$ |f(x)-f(a)|\le M |x-a|$$ where $M$ depends on your $ x$, $a$,  and $\epsilon.$

Then you want to make $M\delta <\epsilon.$

The process goes from trivial to very tricky depending on f(x).

For example $f(x)=1/x$ and $a=0.25$ requires showing $|1/x - 4| \le M|x-0.25|$ for some $M>0.$

Knowing that $|1/x-1/0.25|= \frac {|x-0.25|}{|0.25x|}$ and if $|x-0.25|<0.1$, then $0.25x>0.0375$, we can choose $M=1/.0375\approx 26.66,$ and choose $\ \delta = \min \{0.1,\epsilon /27\}$.
Thus if $|x-0.25|<\delta $, then we have $|1/x-4|=\frac {|x-0.25|}{|0.25x|}<(\epsilon /27)(\frac{1}{0.0375})<\epsilon$

Comment: But is there any way to get a formula for $M$ if $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved?  Like if it’s differentiable can you calculate $M$ in terms of the derivative of $f$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  No, because this M, generally  depends also on the point  $a$

Comment: OK, but is it possible to get an explicit formula for $M$ in terms of $f$, $a$, and $\epsilon$?  Using the derivative of $f$, the integral of $f$, the inverse function of $f$ etc.?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Only for very special  cases such as constant or linear functions.

Comment: $M$ should not depend on $x$.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I found a formula that works for all polynomials, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if one can find an upper bound $B$ for $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a} \right\vert$ on some deleted $p$-neighborhood of $a$ then $\delta=\min\left\{p,\frac{\epsilon}{B}\right\}$

Lemma: If for some $p>0$ and $x\in(a-p,a)\cup(a,a+p) $, it is true that

$$\left\vert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a} \right\vert\le B$$

for some $B>0$ then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$.

Let $\delta=\min\left\{ p,\frac{\epsilon}{B}\right\}$ and $|x-a|<\delta$.  Then $|x-a|<p$, so $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a} \right\vert\le B$. Furthermore, $|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{B}$. Thus $\vert f(x)-L|\vert<\epsilon$. So $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

This approach can work when the function does not have a vertical tangent at $x=a$.

Example: Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^3+2x}{x+2}=3$

Then we must find an upper bound $B$ on some interval about $a=2$. It is simplest first to try $p=1$ and adjust the value later if necessary.

So we try to find an upper bound $B$ on $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a} \right\vert$ on the set $(1,2)\cup(2,3)$.

A bit of algebra will show that $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-L}{x-a} \right\vert=\vert(x+1)^2+2\vert$ on $(1,2)\cup(2,3)$. Since $(x+1)^2+2$ is a parabola, concave up with vertex $(-1,2)$ it is increasing on $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ so it will have its largest value, $18$ at $x=3$. Thus we may let $B=18$.

Now let $\epsilon>0$, $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{18}\right\}$ and $\vert x-2\vert<\delta$. Then $|x-2|<1$ so $\vert(x+1)^2+2\vert=\left\vert\frac{\frac{x^2+2x}{x+2}-3}{x-2}\right\vert<18$. Furthermore, $|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{18}$ so $|x-2|\cdot\left\vert\frac{\frac{x^2+2x}{x+2}-3}{x-2}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{x^2+2x}{x+2}-3\right\vert<18\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{18}=\epsilon$

So $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^3+2x}{x+2}=3$

Comment: But is there any way to get a formula for $B$, at least if $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved, like differentiable and the like?

Comment: No, I do not think there is a general formula for $B$. But if you can graph $\left\vert\dfrac{f(x)-L}{x-a}\right\vert$ in the region around $a$ that can give an idea of how big $B$ should be and how small to make the interval. Then you can try to show it mathematically.